# Simplyfied regex in favour of maintability and readability

Tags: php, regex

I've created a regex which seems to do it's job well, but 1) I'm using a part of it somewhere else in my programm and 2) it is not easy readable. And as I am not a guru in regexes and maybe I will not write any regex within the next twelve month, if I would have to maintain it later, it will be difficult.
As my purpose for the regex is a bit more complex, I try to explain simplified what I'm doing:

I've a text (coming from a rich text editor) and try to find single literals and replace them with a custom tag. Some tags can replace each occurrences in the text, and some only a specific occurence. Which occurence to replace, I figured out in another part of my programm. Some replacements are links, so I have to make sure the occurence of the literal is not allready surrounded by a link. If so,then I have to find the next occurence instead. Finding the nodes and the positions of the literals which are in a link tag, I'm also doing in another part of the programm with php dom parser.  Example:

**Searchwords can be almost everything, even single letters**: word h T. G/L 
And they can occur between whitspaces, in tags, surrounded by any kind of brackets or questionmarks and it can be that there is punctuation directly after the literal.

**How I'm doing this:**
With the following code I'm getting all matches of the specific literal I'm search for (surrounded by questionmarks is still missing here):

```
$quotedLiteral = preg_quote($literal);
$regex = '/(?<=[\s\>({[])'.$quotedLiteral.'(?=[\s\<\p{P}])/mu';
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matchesAll, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Then, if it matters for the kind of replacement,  I'm comparing the positions of the matches with the positions of the literals inside links, and if I found a match which is not surrounded by a link, I replace it. With the following piece of code (in another function):

```
$quotedLiteral = preg_quote($literal);
$pattern= "/^((?:(?:.*?(?<=[\s\>({[])$quotedLiteral(?=[\s\<\p{P}])){" . --$occurrence . "}.*?))(?<=[\s\>({[])$quotedLiteral(?=[\s\<\p{P}])/smi";
return preg_replace($pattern, "$1$replacement", $text);
```

**The most obvious thing is**, that I repeat the first pattern inside the second pattern. And a whole part in the second pattern, is also written twice. Actually the second pattern is doing the same as the first one, but it finds a specific occurence of it, so I can replace it. This part I've to maintain twice, no more then twice, thats never a good idea.

**The second point is**, that I would love to see a much simpler and more readable pattern. Even if its splittet in 4 or 5 patterns, each with a single job. Maybe by writing a function wehre my text and literal goes through different steps until I've the matches. But I don't know how to do it!

**The third problem is**, but it doesn't really fit the main topic, I'm doing this with a 4 times nested foreach loops, as I've so many arrays, all with important key and values. I know, I can split it in different functions, but it is one functionality and I do not feel well to split it.

Back to the regex: Is there a strategy/technics/whatever how to simplyfy regexes? Is there a way to use them partly, one after another until I've my results?

**Sampletext:**

```
<p><a href="somenulla.com">Nulla</a> laoreet felis eu tellus volutpat, in lacinia leo faucibus.</p>
<p>Proin id sollicitudin sem. Nullam ornare, elit t venenatis sagittis ornare,</p>
<p>mi felis viverra nulla, ut finibus diam mauris sed erat.</p>
<p>Lorem A. ipsum dolor <strong>ut</strong> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. (nulla)​​​​​​ </p>
<p>Pellentesque egestas, eros eu t accumsan tempus,</p>
<p>enim felis finibus lorem, nec congue ipsum ipsum in augue. Duis iaculis</p>
<p>ut elit at eros semper.</p>
```

**Example Literals:** ut, Nulla, t, A.

For each literal there are one or more replacements, each replacement is eather an a-tag (link) or a custom tag, and the nodevalues of these tags are the literals itself. 
Usually the text is much longer, always different and the single paragraphs too. And the literals sometimes occure 10 times in each text, sometimes with sourrounded by links, or single or at the beginning or end of a sentence and so on. Like a rich text.

Comment: It's much more appreciated if you provide some sample inputs / outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now I can answer myself. It took me two days to study everything I could get and to rework my expressions for the current project I have. But it was worth it!

**At first** I want to point out three pages which helped me really a lot

- [Rexegg](http://www.rexegg.com)
- [RegexBuddy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)
- [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

The last one I knew allready, thats where I build my first Expressions.

**Now back to my initial post:**
Just a little bit more google and trial and error would have shown me, that regex indeed can be commented. And they can just like strings concenated without fearing to break something.

So I wrote me an Utility Class where I have my regexes inside functions now instead each regex just on the place where I want to use it. I'm sure they arent perfect, but they actually fit to the needs of the project. And if once not, I can easily adapt them a bit.

**Now I started really liking writing regular expressions!**

Finally my two functions I'm using for that regex above are looking like this:

```
/**
 * literalMatch
 * This regex matches the literal given in a ckeditors HTML
 * it looks before and behind the found literals if there are only
 * the allowed characters. This way we make sure,
 * we do not match the "B" in "BStU" if we looked for "B"
 *
 * regexp is also used by matchNthOccurenceOfLiteralPattern()
 *
 * final regex looks like:
 * (?<=
 *  [\s\>\"'\/({[]
 * )
 * AG
 * (?=
 *  [\s\<\"'\/\p{P}]
 * )
 *
 * @param string $quotedLiteral our search word
 * @param bool $addModifier
 * @return string
 */
public static function matchAllLiteralsPattern(string $quotedLiteral, bool $addModifier = true) :string
{

    $inlineModifier =  ($addModifier ? self::DELIMITER . '(?x)' : '');

    return $inlineModifier . '
            (?<=                    # positive lookbehind looks whats directy before our literal that means everything in here is allowed directly in front of the literal
                [\s\>\"\'\/({[]     # Inside this square brackets we list some single characters which are allowed to preceed our literal
            )                   
        '
        .$quotedLiteral.        
            '(?=                    # positive lookahead looks whats directy after our literal that means everything in here is allowed directly after of the literal
                [\s\<\"\'\/\p{P}]   # Inside this square brackets we list some single characters which are allowed to follow directly our literal
            )                   
            ' . ($addModifier ? self::DELIMITER . '' : '');
}


/**
 * matchNthOccurenceOfLiteralPattern
 *
 * Basically we match the nth occurence of a literal in text
 * (for replacements)
 * In replacements we would replace the full match
 * (starts where text starts) upto (incl) the literal with
 * the first group we match . replacement.
 *
 * example: return preg_replace($pattern, "$1$replacement", $subject);
 * ($1 refers to the first captured group)
 * 
 * final regex looks like this
 * /(?x)^
 *  (
 *   (?:
 *    (?:.*?
 *     (?<=
 *      [\s\>\"'\/({[]
 *     )
 *     AG
 *     (?=
 *      [\s\<\"'\/\p{P}]
 *     )
 *    ){3}
 *    .*?
 *   )
 *  )
 *  (?<=
 *   [\s\>\"'\/({[]
 *  )
 *  AG
 *  (?=
 *   [\s\<\"'\/\p{P}]
 *  )/
 *
 * @param string $quotedLiteral
 * @param int $occurrence
 * @return string
 */
public static function matchNthOccurenceOfLiteralPattern(string $quotedLiteral, int $occurrence)
{

    $matchAllLiteralsPattern = self::matchAllLiteralsPattern($quotedLiteral, false);

    $inlineModifier =  self::DELIMITER . '(?x)';

    return $inlineModifier . '      # inline modifier x stands for PCRE_EXTENDED which allows us these comments
            ^                       # anchor ensure we start at the begin of the line
                (                   # capturing group matches everything from beginning of the string upto and incl the literal
                    (?:             # non capturing group matches everything upto and excl. our literal
                        (?:         # group matches between the occurence we search for and the occurrence before (or the start of string if we macth the first occurence). we will count how often this matches, but dont need the matches itself
                            .*?     # now we say what we want: any character from start of the text up to our literal. for the literal we need the pattern above, which we use also in other place in our programm
                            ' . $matchAllLiteralsPattern . '
                        )
                        {'. $occurrence .'}
                        .*?         # everything can follow, but we dont need it so we make it lazy
                    )
                )
                ' . $matchAllLiteralsPattern  .  self::DELIMITER . 's';
}
```